# Why is this returning 0? It should output 18446744073709551615, which should fit

Tags: c#, ulong

This code returns 0, where it should return 18446744073709551615, which should fit in a ulong?
When I set it to iterate 63 (rather than 64) times I get 9223372036854775808, which is correct.

```
public static ulong Total()
{
    ulong output = 1ul ; 
    for(var x = 0; x < 64; x++)
    {
        output *= 2;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Regardless of anything else, once you've taken any whole number and multiplied it by 2 you should expect an even result, not an odd one.

Comment: You shifted a 1-bit 64 times to the left. The last shift will shift it out of the 64-bit value, in essence removing it. Think about what would happen if you shift a 1-bit 8 times to the left, in a byte. The last shift would shift it out of the byte.

Answer (score 3):

You are calculating 2^64, which is not 18446744073709551615 but 1844674407370955161**6**. You may notice that when you changed 64 to 63 you got 9223372036854775808 and not 9223372036854775807.

Comment: _"and not 9223372036854775807"_ which *2 would not result in 1844674407370955161**5**, neither.

Comment: This doesn't address the main question which is "Why is this returning 0?"

Answer (score 2):

The calculation you make is out of the capacity of the number of bytes of a `ulong` needed to contains a big value...

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types

You need to use decimal for example:

```cs
public static decimal Total()
{
  decimal output = 1ul;
  for ( var x = 0; x < 64; x++ )
  {
    output *= 2;
  }
  return output;
}
```

This output `18446744073709551616`.

Indeed, if we add the `checked` keyword to the method using `ulong`:

```cs
public static ulong Total()
{
  ulong output = 1ul;
  for ( var x = 0; x < 64; x++ )
  {
    output = checked(output * 2);
  }
  return output;
}
```

We get an overflow exception.

You can also use `System.Numerics.BigInteger` for very huge integers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger